# How to get WiPi WiFi USB dongle working on Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, wifi, wireless

I've got a [Wi-Pi](http://www.newark.com/element14/wipi/module-wifi-usb-for-raspberry-pi/dp/07W8938) WiFi USB dongle and a Raspberry Pi model B with Raspbian wheezy (updated/upgraded)
but I can't get the wipy to work.

Every single time I connect the wipy the Raspberry Pi reboot.

I see these messages on boot:

[image: wifi errors]

and of course I don't see `wlan0` in `wpa_gui`.

I've also tried connecting the Wi-Pi a the active/powered usb port of a D-Link USB hub powered at 5V/3A. The RPi didn't reboot this time but still didn't work (same "Failed to bring up wlan0" message when I manually reboot).

How can I get the Wi-Pi working ?

Comment: Q: What's a "wipy"?

Comment: sorry, meant [WiPi](http://uk.farnell.com/jsp/search/productdetail.jsp?SKU=2133900), edited the question now.

Comment: Plug wifi adapter before boot.if you plug it after boot it will reboot because lack of power. For failed wlan0 messages, please update your question with contents of /etc/network/interfaces file.

Comment: Do you have a DHCP server on your network?  The DHCPDISCOVER message indicate that your Pi is trying to obtain an IP address and isn't getting a response back.  What does `iwconfig` display on your system?

Comment: @HeatfanJohn We should do, all other computers get they're IPs assigned by a DHCP server. The problem with iwconfig is I get a `segmentation fault` when I run the command which is worrying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get ride of that... Get this: [Edimax EW-7811Un 150Mbps 11n Wi-Fi USB Adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003MTTJOY)

Plug it in, will work fine.

When the command prompt comes up type:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Then add whatever is missing from this to what you see:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
auto wlan0


iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid "ssid"
wpa-psk "password"
```

This will be worry free forever.

Comment: have ordered, one. In the meantime, I've made sure /etc/network/interfaces looks like the above(with the correct ssid and pass of course). This time in the boot sequence things looked better, and the WiPy's led turned on, but once I started wpa_gui I noticed wlan0 still wasn't available. Same result with wicd

Comment: Yea, sounds like the dongle you have is a dud.  While it is possible to get the driver for it and install it in the right directory, the one I recommend is going to be totally problem free.

Comment: Perhaps, although I have ordered two and it's a bit weird that two would be duds

Comment: Then its probably a driver issue...  You can try to tackle that... OR... Just get something that works out of the box ; )

Comment: The WiPY eventually worked, although I'm not happy that the RPi reboots every single time I plug it back into the USB port. The Edimax came today as well and it worked just fine. The RPI doesn't reboot if I remove it/plug it back in and wifi connection is back on, where as the wipy needs a reboot to work. Sticking with the edimax for now. The above config was also handy (thanks (+1))

Comment: Awesome, I'm stoked it worked

Comment: My WiPi worked after commenting out the wpa_supplicant, and then making the edits listed here. Kind of weird how that works.